# Thread modeling in reactive frameworks

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, reactive-programming, vert.x

I have a question related to thread modeling of reactive frameworks, like Vert.x.

So frameworks like Vert.x work on the idea of  having main threads same as number of cores so that there is not much context switching required as its a costly operation. And then we have everything modeled as event. For eg., an incoming http request is an event, receiving response from DB is also an event and so on. And idea is to make sure that handler tasks running on main threads are not blocking, and if we do have something time consuming then put it on worker thread. For eg, while incoming http request is handled on main thread, fetching data from DB needed to serve that request is done on worker thread.

But how does it solve problem of context switching. As with this approach we can easily have huge number of simultaneous worker threads, which would require context switching.

So what actually is the winner here?

Comment: It does not create threads for each pending operation. Each pending operation completion is an event, for example, DB operation completion is an event. It has event loop thread, which is continuously processing these events.

Comment: Then what do we have worker threads for? My understanding is that blocking operations are pushed to worker threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reactive frameworks like Vert.x, I/O operations that use the APIs provided by the framework do not block threads. So when you make an HTTP request, or fetch data from a DB (using a non-blocking DB driver), the work is not sent to a worker thread. The I/O request runs in the background, without blocking your event loop thread (or any other thread), and once a response is available, the framework takes care of executing your callback, completing the future, etc. So in an application where no blocking operations are required, there is very little context switching, as a single thread can be running many I/O operations concurrently (and therefore servicing many requests) without blocking.

Worker threads are only required when you have to do a long-running, blocking operation. Examples of this include expensive mathematical calculations, parsing a large amount of text, or using an API that does blocking I/O (like the JDBC API). In those cases, you use a worker thread or thread pool to do the blocking, so that the event loop stays free to service other requests. You do pay a context switching penalty here, though typically you'd use a small worker thread pool, so the number of running threads should not be large.

So, to reap the benefits of reduced context switching, you have to make sure your application is primarily using native non-blocking APIs.